# jdbcTemplate.query Running slow with millions of records

Tags: db2, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I don't know why this query is running very slow to execute if table has more records of 180 millions.Database I am connecting is DB2.

```
public CustomerEmailFreq getFreqCodeByEmail(String email, String domain) {
CustomerEmailFreq customerEmailFreq = new CustomerEmailFreq();
Map namedParameters = new HashMap();
namedParameters.put("email", email);
namedParameters.put("domain", domain);

String sql = "select freq_cde,email_local,email_domain,last_src_date,last_src_time from ADDRESS where upper(email_local)=upper(:email) and upper(email_domain)=upper(:domain) ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(LAST_SRC_DATE,LAST_SRC_TIME) DESC FOR READ ONLY WITH UR FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY";

this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, (rs, rowNum) ->

{
    customerEmailFreq.setEmailDomain(rs.getString("EMAIL_DOMAIN").trim());
    customerEmailFreq.setEmailLocal(rs.getString("EMAIL_LOCAL").trim());
    customerEmailFreq.setFreqCode(rs.getString("FREQ_CDE"));
    customerEmailFreq.setLastSrcDate(rs.getString("LAST_SRC_DATE"));
    customerEmailFreq.setLastSrcTime(rs.getString("LAST_SRC_TIME"));
    return null;

});
return customerEmailFreq;
```

}

Any hints to help this out.

Comment: how long does the query take when you run it directly on the db?  
why are you returning null?

Comment: its taking more than 4 mins.As i have used lambda expression so have to return null.

Comment: Why do you expect it to run fast?

Comment: because table index are set up on columns email_local,email_domain.Which i have used in the where clause so expecting to run faster.

Comment: IF the index on columns email_local, email_domain is not an expression-based index, and with suitable runstats collected, then the  4-minute run time may be due to a poor access plan. That's because you are using a function (UPPER()) on two predicates. If it is a plain index (or indexes) then DB2 would ignore that index because of that UPPER().  Also you need to know the isolation-level used, and the DB2-server operating-system platform and DB2-version because these determine whether expression-based indexes are available.     You can get the access plan from DB2 to verify these things.

Answer (score 1):

180 million rows is some serious number. So things should be expected to run for a while if they can't use indexes to limit the number of blocks accessed in the database.

In the comments you answer the question

> Why do you expect it to run fast?

With

> because table index are set up on columns `email_local`, `email_domain`. Which I have used in the where clause so expecting to run faster.

The problem is, you are most likely not using these indexes.

1. If they are actually multiple indexes the database will most likely only use one. Most databases can't combine multiple indexes most of the time.
2. If your where clause looks like this:

   ```
    where upper(email_local)=upper(:email) and upper(email_domain)=upper(:domain)
   ```

   This means you are applying the where clause not to the indexed columns, but to function results based on those columns. This makes the index mostly useless.

Here is what you can do (there might be more, not a DB2 expert here)

1. [add a function based index](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/legacy?lang=en). This is the one you should really do. The others are more for cases where you can't do this one (different RDBMS, old version, mad DB admin)
2. add columns with the uppercased names to the table and index those and use them in the query.
3. drop the `upper` on the columns in the where clause. This obviously will change your query and probably won't be acceptable.
4. As a final really hacky approach you can add constraints that use the index:

   ```
    where column between lower(:value) and upper(:value) and upper(column) = upper(:value)
   ```

   You'd need to adapt this approach to multiple columns and make sure that any non ascii characters are sorted in as expected (which they won't).

In any case it is a good idea to look at your statements [explain plan](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/10?topic=statements-explain) and compare it before and after the changes. If you work with hundreds of millions of rows you will need this tool.

Comment: Thanks Jens let me take a look